# Label objects not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

Setup a graph using matplotlib which is working properly (see image below), but when I try to add a legend I get the following error: `UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on indivial plots.`

Here's the code I'm using to define the lines that I want in the legend and draw the legend:

```
#Moving average labels
smaLabel1 = str(SMA1)+'d SMA'
smaLabel2 = str(SMA2)+'d SMA'
smaLabel3 = str(SMA3)+'d SMA'

#Add SMAs to chart
ax1.plot(ind, avg1, '#5998ff', label=smaLabel1, linewidth=1)
ax1.plot(ind, avg2, '#ffbb82', label=smaLabel2, linewidth=1)
ax1.plot(ind, avg3, '#d689c4', label=smaLabel3, linewidth=1)
""" End SMA additions """

#Add legend
plt.legend()
```

I've checked the `smaLabel` variables, and all hold the correct strings. Anyone know why the labels aren't registering?

[image]

Comment: In the code you're using, what occurs between the last ax1.plot(..., legend=...) and plt.legend()? (e.g., plt.grid(), and so on)

Comment: JDGD have you fixed the sample-code above after @CT-Zhu  advice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must have plot the candle plots and the volume before plotting the SMA. The candle plot doesn't have any labeled object, when you call the `plt.legend()`, it tries to plot a label for every plot on the current axes. Therefore, you get this `UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on indivial plots.`

To solve it, I hope it is clear at this point, simply requires you to plot the SMA's very first, before the candle plot, and call the `legend()` right after that before any other plots being generated.

Comment: Thank you! Did not realize I needed to plot the SMAs before the candlestick. Changed the declare order and everything is working now.